# Can an unsigned long become negative when multiplied by a float?

Tags: c, implicit-conversion

The title is probably ill-chosen, but I could not find a good one-line summary for this question. My problem is that I cannot make sense of what my compiler is doing, and I wonder whether I found a bug in the compiler... or in my understanding of the C language.

My understanding is that:

- `- 1UL == ULONG_MAX`, and this is safe since the overflow behavior of unsigned numbers is well defined
- the product `(- 1UL) * 1.0f` involves the conversion of the left operand to float, and this conversion preserves the value (namely `ULONG_MAX`) except for rounding errors

So far my compiler agrees, unless `1UL` comes from a variable. Here is my test program, with its output as comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long one = 1;
    unsigned long minus_one = - one;
    printf("%lu\n", - one);            // 18446744073709551615
    printf("%g\n", minus_one * 1.0f);  // 1.84467e+19
    printf("%g\n", (- one) * 1.0);     // 1.84467e+19
    printf("%g\n", (- 1UL) * 1.0f);    // 1.84467e+19
    printf("%g\n", (- one) * 1.0f);    // -1
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot make sense of the last output. I tried various optimization levels, and various language standards (C90, C99 and C11) with identical results. Anyone a clue?

Environment: gcc 4.8.1 / Ubuntu Linux 14.04 / x86-64 (I32LP64)

**Edit**: I just noticed that my question may be a duplicate of [combination of unary minus and float conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17611799).

Comment: The program gives the expected output in Visual Studio, and in my VM (Ubuntu 10.04, gcc 4.4.3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in gcc 4.8. I have the same behavior as you with 4.8, but gcc 4.9 and clang show the corrected behavior.

Comment: Can you verify that it is a bug? I could be UB, in which case even 4.8 is *"correct"*.

Comment: @user694733: It is just in the next paragraph of what you cited: *If the value being
converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented
exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen
in an implementation-defined manner.*

Comment: That seems to be correct. If `long` is 32-bit on that platform, `float` should have enough range, in which case UB is ruled out.

Comment: `long` is 64-bit, but that is still in the range of `float`.